# Actual redirect link is different from the link in faces-configs.xml when it has parmeters

Tags: jsf-2

In face-configs.xml,

```
    <navigation-rule>
     <from-view-id>/login.jspx</from-view-id>
           <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.jspx?Error=InvalidUser</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
      </navigation-rule>
```

When Login return “failure”, the return page is login.jspx but not login.jspx?Error=InvalidUser in the website address.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you tagged the question as JSF 2.0, why are you still using config file for navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP/JSPX is much different from JSF.while going with JSF2.x versions it is best suggested to use a JSF page(.xhtml) for the UI development.
Instead of fixing the above error I would suggest you to do the application either completely using JSF or JSP, not advisable to merge both and get into compatibility issues.

Also in JSF-2.x versions we dont need the navigation-rules to be defined in faces-config.xml, they can be configured the web page or the respective managed bean itself

```
 <h:commandLink id = "submitBtn" value="New Page" action="#{bean.showPage}">
 </h:commandLink>
```

bean can have a method

```
public String showPage(){
  return "\login.xhtml";
}
```

or

```
<h:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Submit" action="Response.jsp">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify them as `<view-param>` in the `<redirect>`, not in the `<to-view-id>`.

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/login.jspx</to-view-id>
    <redirect>
        <view-param>
            <name>Error</name>
            <value>InvalidUser</value>
        </view-param>
    </redirect>
</navigation-case>
```

Since JSF 2.0 new implicit navigation feature it's possible to get rid of navigation cases altogether. The above can be replaced by returning the following string in action method.

```
public String login() {
    // ...

    if (failure) {
        return "/login.jspx?Error=InvalidUser&faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```